# I want to access object of mysqlconnection from one class to another form

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

**CODE A(CLASS)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace eBayERPSolution
{     
    public class dbconnection
    {           
        int flag = 0;

        public int Flag
        {
            get { return flag; }    
        }

        public dbconnection()
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlconnect"].ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                con.Open();// I WANT TO ACCESS THIS CON OBJECT IN ANOTHER FORM
                flag = 1;
            }    
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                flag = 0;
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message );    
            }               
       }    
    }
}
```

**CODE B (FORM)**

```
public  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dbconnection check = new dbconnection();
    if (check.Flag == 0)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }

    try
    {
         string query = "INSERT INTO ebayerp_sales (invdate,invno,paisapayid,phonenumber,emailid,paymentrecdate,customername,buyerid,billingaddress,shippingaddress,shippingpatner,awbno,shippingdate,status) VALUES('" + invdate.Text + "','" + int.Parse(invno.Text) + "','" + int.Parse(paisapayidtbox.Text) + "','" + int.Parse(phonenumbertbox.Text) + "','" + emailidtbox.Text + "','" + paymentrecdatetbox.Text + "','" + customernametbox.Text + "','" + buyeridtbox.Text + "','" + billingaddresstbox.Text + "','" + shippingaddresstbox.Text + "','" + shippingpatnertbox.Text + "','" + awbnotbox.Text + "','" + shippingdatetbox.Text  + "','" + statustbox.Text  + "')";
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,---------------);//I WANT TO ACCESS CON OBJECT THERE.
```

Comment: You must improve the way you are making questions. This one has a very low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just publish the `MySqlConnection` object as a property of your `dbconnection` class.

```
public class dbconnection
{
    MySqlConnection connection;
    int flag = 0;

    public int Flag
    {
        get { return flag; }    
    }

    public MySqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return this.connection; }
    }

    public dbconnection()
    {
        this.connection = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlconnect"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            this.connection.Open();
            flag = 1;
        }    
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            flag = 0;
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message );    
        }               
   }    
}
```

... and use it from your windows form.

```
var myDbConnection = new dbconnection();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, myDbConnection.Connection);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH.i AM A BEGINER

Comment: hi sir can you explain to me what happen on this line of code? i am new in c#.

`public MySqlConnection Connection
    {
       get { return this.connection; }
    }`

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday these code you are referencing is a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) that allows access to the `connection` variable, that is private on the class and it is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

As it is now, your MySqlConnection object is declared as a local variable in the constructor. Instead, make it a property.

```
public class DbConnection
{
    ...

    public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public DbConnection()
    {
        Connection = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlconnect"].ConnectionString);
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a helper class (aka wrapper), something like this or use this
[MySqlHelper](http://updatesinit.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/helper-class-for-dot-net-and-mysql/). Also you can go for [DbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) and [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx) for some generic approach, if you like.